# Curl returns response code 200 when using ip address with any (valid/invalid)) credentials

Tags: curl

I am using below CURL to get the response:

result=$(curl -L -1 -k -u ${AUTH_USER}:${AUTH_PASSWORD} -b cookies1.txt -c cookies1.txt https://${SERVER_HOST}:8093/rest/dec/connect -s -o /dev/null -w "\nHTTP code: %{http_code}")

NOTE : URL "https://${SERVER_HOST}:8093/rest/dec/connect" redirect to another urls.

Case 1 : When I pass valid AUTH_USER, AUTH_PASSWORD & hostname as SERVER_HOST, it returns response, ie. 200, which is correct.

Case 2 : When I pass invalid AUTH_USER, AUTH_PASSWORD & hostname as SERVER_HOST, it returns response, ie. 401, which is correct.

Case 3 : When I pass invalid AUTH_USER, AUTH_PASSWORD & IP address as SERVER_HOST, it returns response, ie. 200, which is INCORRECT.

Above curl command is working fine, when I use hostname as "SERVER_HOST".

As I am facing issue when I use IP Address as "SERVER_HOST". Any ways to handle this ?

Comment: Sounds like less of a cURL issue, and more of one of the remote server that you are connecting to ... that seems to behave differently, based on whether you access it via a host name, or just an IP address. Could simply be falling back to a default vhost or something like that, that is not configured to require auth ...

Comment: and please be aware that using `-k` makes your connection totally insecure